# jQuery Remodal shows 'opened' state, but does not display

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, remodal

I'm using jQuery Remodal in combination with PHP. I'm displaying the jQuery code for launching when the page loads with some server-side variables. I've used Remodal for years, without a problem. But I'm experiencing some odd behavior that is intermittent.

Basically, 50% of the time, the modal fires and behaves expectedly, but other times, the page scrollbar goes away (Remodal launch), no Remodal window, and the console says 'opened.' I hit refresh, same thing happened. I hit refresh, and the modal appears. I hit refresh again, no modal. Very strange.

```js
$(function() {
  var options = {
    hashTracking: false,
  };
  var bundleModal = $('[data-remodal-id=BundleModal]').remodal(options);
  console.log(bundleModal.getState());
  bundleModal.close();
  console.log(bundleModal.getState());
  bundleModal.open();
  console.log(bundleModal.getState());
  $('.modal-reconfigure').click(function() {
    bundleModal.close();
    bundleModal.destroy();
  });
  $('.modal-add').click(function() {
    $('form#bundleprocess').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remodal/1.1.1/remodal-default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remodal/1.1.1/remodal.min.js"></script>

<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="BundleModal">
  Your Bundle Is Complete!<br /><br />
  <div clasS="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="modal-add btn radius orange blob">Add Bundle To Cart</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="modal-reconfigure btn radius grey">Reconfigure</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I reload the page and I have the issue, the console says:

```
closed
closed
opened
```

So it partially opens since the scrollbar goes away. Opacity layer doesn't show. Obviously the div doesn't appear. But again, if I hit refresh a few times, it may show. Very intermittent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the remodal-is-initialized class to the modal container div:

```
<div class="remodal remodal-is-initialized" data-remodal-id="BundleModal">
```